# Echo set specific time

Tags: windows, batch-file

I use a code like this to get current time in Windows Bash:

```
set hour=%TIME:~0,2%
set minute=%TIME:~3,2%
set second=%TIME:~6,2%
```

But I need a current time +13 seconds. Is there any ways to get this?

Comment: Create EXE file and get the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumming a 24h time *hh:mm:ss,cc* format,

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=:., " %%a in ("%time%") do (
        set /a  "second=100%%c %% 100 +13", ^
                "minute=100%%b %% 100 +second/60", ^
                "hour=(100%%a %% 100 +minute/60) %% 24 +100", ^
                "minute=minute %% 60 +100", ^
                "second=second %% 60 +100"
    )
    echo %time%
    echo %hour:~-2%:%minute:~-2%:%second:~-2%
```

The time string is tokenized (yes, substring operations are equally valid, but i see this as an easier way), so the hour is retrieved in `%%a`, minutes in `%%b` and seconds in `%%c` and the calcs done

For the three hour elements, the retrieved value from the `%time%` string are prefixed with `100` and then a `mod 100` operation is done, all to avoid the problem with `08` and `09` values being considered as wrong octal values. Once the correct decimal values are retrieved we can operate

```
second = currentSeconds + 13
minute = currentMinutes + 1 ( if second > 60 )
hour = currentHour + 1 (if minute > 60 ) adjusted to 24h + 100 (for padding)
minute = minute adjusted to 0-59 range + 100 (for padding)
second = second adjusted to 0-59 range + 100 (for padding)
```

We end with values in the range 100-159 in second, 100-159 in minute, 100-123 in hour. That way we can properly output padded time elements retrieving the last two digits from each of the variables.

Comment: What if the 13 seconds spans the transition from standard to daylight savings time (or vice versa)? - evil grin :-)

Comment: @dbenham, ;) it can be [worse](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6841479/2861476). But anyway, a time plus 13 seconds operation is not affected by daylight savings, intercalar seconds, or UTC coordination. It is a pure only time operation, there is no date, so none of the indicated considerations are applicable. **BUT** of course this is *"probably"* something to take in consideration in the rest of the code that uses this calcs. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the other solutions, but I calculate first the seconds of the day, then adding 13.
And then format the resulting number back to a hh:mm:ss format.

```
rem ** Calculate the seconds of the day
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=:., " %%a in ("%time: =0%") do (
    set /a  "secOfDay=1%%c %% 100 + 60*(1%%b %% 100) + 3600*(1%%a %% 100 )"
)

REM ** Add the desired offset
set /a timePlus13sec=secOfDay+13

REM ** Convert the new time to the HH:mm:ss format
set /a sec=100+timePlus13sec %% 60
set /a temp=timePlus13sec / 60
set /a min=100+temp %% 60
set /a hour=100+(temp / 60) %% 24

echo %hour:~-2%:%min:~-2%:%sec:~-2%
```

Answer (score 1):

This method uses JScript auxiliary code, so it is always correct:

```
@echo off

echo d=new Date();d.setTime(d.getTime()+13000);WScript.Echo(d.toString().split(' ')[3]);> test.js

for /F %%a in ('cscript //nologo test.js') do set timeAhead=%%a
echo Time plus 13 seconds: %timeAhead%
```

Answer (score 0):

*I need a current time +13 seconds*. Adding 13 and seconds seems to be easiest task, but there are some intricacies:

- all numeric values in `set /A` that start with zeros are treated as
  octal but 08 and 09 are not valid octal digits. Cf. next workaround with
  `%%` *modulus* operator: `set /A "val=100%lav%%%100"`
- more than 59 seconds value affects minutes, more than 59 minutes
  value influences hours, more than 23 hours value seems to be impossible
  as well...

The script:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
@SETLOCAL
set "myTIME=%TIME%"
call :plus13 "%myTIME%" 6 13 60 second carry
call :plus13 "%myTIME%" 3 %carry% 60 minute carry
call :plus13 "%myTIME%" 0 %carry% 24 hour carry
echo "%myTIME%" 
echo "%hour% %minute% %second%"
@ENDLOCAL
@goto :eof

:: plus13 procedure
:: %1 = time value
:: %2 = position in time
:: %3 = value to add
:: %4 = threshold
:: %5 = name of time variable
:: %6 = name of carry variable
:plus13
@SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set "lav=%~1"
set "lav=!lav:~%2,2!"
set /A "val=100%lav%%%100"
set /A "val+=%3"
if %val% GEQ %4 (
  set /A "val-=%4"
  set /A "car=1"
) else (set /a "car=0")
if %val% LSS 10 set "val=0%val%"
@ENDLOCAL&set %5=%val%&set %6=%car%&goto :eof
```

Output:

```
C:\...>time13s
"11:51:49,50"
"11 52 02"
```